display input box value when triggered by button click
The project i am creating in React.js requires me to take in input from the user and display it on the webpage, i want my balance button to display the input value when clicked but currently when i enter a value in the input box it displays automatically rather than waiting for the button click to be triggered before displaying on the webpage.
from my code below i was wondering if i am missing something like a handleClick function or add event handlers? As i am new to working with React.js please help??
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function BalanceInput() {
  const [userBalance, setUserBalance] = useState(0);

  function displayBalance() {
    setUserBalance(0);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label for="balanceInput">Enter Bank Balance: </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(event) => setUserBalance(event.target.value)}
        id="balanceInput"
        placeholder="Enter balance here"
        defaultValue={0}
      />

      <h3>Current Balance: {userBalance}</h3>
      <button onClick={displayBalance}>Balance</button>
    </div>
  );
}


Just add a separate state that is triggered by the button click, and then use that boolean to determine whether to show the current value of the input or zero.
Note: the label property for in React is htmlFor.


const { useState } = React;

function BalanceInput() {
  const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);
  const [userBalance, setUserBalance] = useState(0);

  function handleChange(event) {
    if (userBalance > 0) {
      setUserBalance(0);
      setButtonClicked(false);
    }
    setUserBalance(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="balanceInput">Enter Bank Balance: </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        id="balanceInput"
        placeholder="Enter balance here"
        defaultValue={0}
      />
      <h3>Current Balance: {buttonClicked ? userBalance : 0}</h3>
      <button onClick={() => setButtonClicked(true)}>Balance</button>
    </div>
  );
}
const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<BalanceInput />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>




this does resolve my problem however when I delete my input and enter a new one the value automatically displays again without clicking the button first? @Andy

@NewQode10 Updated answer which resets the balance. Or you could have a reset button. There are a few ways to solve this.
